# Get facebook pages URls based on KeyWords

Tags: php, python, facebook, r, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all facebook pages URLs at dynamic time which contain the searched KeyWord.If i want get all the pages URL's which contain "**data science**" so what i do just search on my fb search bar and get
[data science seached pages](https://www.facebook.com/search/more/?q=data%20science&sid=0.00922399596311152).It contain all the pages related to data science,Is it possible to make app in facebook that allow such search at run time an return URL's

```
fb_page <- getPage(page="JamiesItalianAU", token=fb_oauth)
```

fetched data only from specific page but not from specific search

```
fb_page1 <- getPage(page="Facebook Data Science", token=fb_oauth)
Error in fromJSON(rawToChar(url.data$content)) : unexpected character '<'
```

Is it possible to get facebook pages based on keywords.Any help,thanks.

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvote so that i woudnt post such question here.

Comment: I didn't downvote but i'd say it is due to the fact that it is quite hard to understand what you want. You want to build a facebook app or an app using facebook? Why did you tag your question with "r"? Why did you tag your question with python?

Comment: @AndreschSerj thanks for your comment,this is just because i am in depended of technology as far as motto is achieved and just because i have tried in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#types to refer to the Page Search syntax of the Graph API. Please note that you need an App Access Token to be able to search for Pages.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=platform&type=page ,where page cannot be any search type of object as in "Facebook Data Science".

Comment: fb_oauth token is* for token access only.

Comment: I still not get what you want to say. Using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook+data+science&type=page&access_token={your_app_access_token} works definitely!

Comment: thank you very much yeah its work,I think i wrote query in a wrong fashion.